# Is there a way to represent functions using circles, similar to how Taylor series work?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, circles, approximation

I was curious whether or not there is a method of representing a function as an infinite amount of circles multiplied or added or something?

Similar to a Taylor series, such that the method would approximate the function.

Comment: By ‘representing a function as an infinite amount of circles’, do you mean a function expressed in terms of equations of circles?

Comment: Circles aren't functions so it's hard to use them to approximate functions. You may be interested in Fourier series though.

Comment: @Tavish yeah something like that.

Comment: It’s very unlikely that any curve other than one (or more) circles can be expressed as such.

Comment: It is possible to approximate sufficiently smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with circles. These are known as [osculating circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle); however, I don't know precisely how well these things approximate. (I'm aware this doesn't quite answer your specific question).

Comment: I think you ask a reasonable question, but it needs to be phrased more precisely. Let's say a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is *locally a circle at $x_0$* if there exists some point $c \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and some $r,\epsilon>0$ such that $||c-(x,f(x))||=r$ for all $x \in (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$. Now, suppose we're given a sufficiently smooth arbitrary function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Must there exist a sequence $\{g_n\}$ with each $g_i$ locally a circle at $x_0$ such that $g_n \to g$ pointwise on some open set containing $x_0$?

Comment: Please show us graphically what you have in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "circles added or multiplied or something" ? As said above, circles are not functions and addition/multiplication of circles has little meaning.

Comment: @Tavish What would it mean if there was a way of expressing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can. Here is one example. Consider the template function

$$t\to f(t) = \sqrt{1-t^2},\,\,\, t\in[-1,1]$$

This is a half-circle. Now let us build a family of scaled and translated templates for $n\in \mathbb Z^+, k\in \mathbb Z$:

$$g_{n,k}(t) = f\left(\frac{t}{2^{n-1}}-k\right)$$

These will look something like this:

[image]

If we fit with a usual least-squares regression, we can approximate the Taylor basis functions on $[-1,1]$:
[image]

Comment: Thanks alot but I'm only a Higherschooler and was wondering what I should research in order to better understand this.

Comment: @ElbraidoGunaratnam Aha. I think to start a bit with beginners linear algebra could be possible in high school. I don't know if you have done any computer programming before. You can get some software to experiment with. Maybe you can find a student license for Matlab. Otherwise Gnu Octave and Python are really good free softwares for numerical linear algebra. There are lots of material online which you can use. Wikipedia is a good start for example.